# Remote HTTP connections IIS7

Tags: iis, configuration

How do I allow remote connections from WAN to IIS? I've already set port forwarding. When I try `nmap` from remote machine I see port 80 open, but every connection results in timeout. Firewall is also down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try connecting via IP address instead of DNS hostname. Also when using a hostname make sure that the [host headers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(WS.10).aspx) are configured correctly.